# Replacing one of the integrals in the multiple integral with an analytical solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching, replacement, symbolic, hold

Problem consist in simplifying complicated multiple numerical integral, where I know analytical solution for a subset of them. Integrand is of the form

```
E^(I vecr.A + I vecrp.B + I (vecr.C + vecrp.D)) (vecr.D vecrp.C - vecr.vecrp D.C),
```

where `vecr`, `vecrp`, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are real 3-vectors. I know the analytical solution of a double integral over vecr and vecrp and I want to substitute them, so Mathematica needs to recognize that ''Integral over vecr...*Exp[...*r]->f[r]'' and ''Integral over vecrp...*Exp[...*rp]->f[rp]''. vecr is given by

```
vecr = {r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Cos[φ],  r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Sin[φ], r*μ};
```

and similarly for vecrp.

Problem with the brute force approach where Mathematica does this analytical calculations is that it needs too much time (I haven't seen that Mathematica finishes the calculation  at all).

Solution of

```
Table[Integrate[ vecr[[i]]*r^2*Exp[I*veck.vecr], {φ, 0, 2*Pi}, {μ, -1,  1}, {r, 0, R}] , {i, 1, Length[vecr]}]
```

is

```
I*12*Pi*R^5*(Sin[k*R]/(k*R)^5 - Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^4 -    Sin[k*R]/(3*(k*R)^3))*veck,
```

where

```
veck = {k*Cos[φk]*Sqrt[1 - μk^2], k*Sin [φk]*Sqrt[1 - μk^2], k*μk}
```

---

For a toy-example

```
Integrate[y*Exp[-t], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 1, 5}
```

where I know that

```
Integrate[y, {y, 1, 5}]
```

is equal to 12 I tried

```
a[t_] :=  HoldForm[Integrate[y*Exp[-t], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 1, 5}]]
a[t] /. HoldForm[Integrate[y, {y, 1, 5}] -> 12]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can adapt this

```
veck = {k*Cos[φk]*Sqrt[1 - μk^2], k*Sin[φk]*Sqrt[1 - μk^2], k*μk};
vecr = {r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Cos[φ], r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Sin[φ], r*μ};
partial = Table[Integrate[vecr[[i]]*r^2*Exp[I*veck.vecr], {r,0,R}],{i,1,Length[vecr]}]
```

which will perform your integral over r.

Then to perform the integral over the remaining two variables

```
Map[Integrate[#, {φ, 0, 2*Pi}, {μ, -1, 1}]&, partial]
```

You can look up `Map` in the help system and see how it is going to take each item in `partial` one at a time, insert that in the place of that `#`, and perform `Integrate` on that.

I am not convinced this is really going to solve your problem, but you can try this on simpler examples and see if you can convince yourself that it will let you do what you asked to do.